# What would prevent Telnet connections to Universe on Windows 8

Tags: telnet, universe

I've installed Universe Personal Edition on a Windows 8.1 virtual machine that's hosted in VMWare. I also have installed a terminal emulator (SecureCRT) in the VM. I am able to access Universe via the Universe Shell, but not via telnet on port 23.

I've confirmed that the uvtelnet service is running, and that it's listening on port 23, as confirmed by `netstat -a`. When I stop the service, `netstat -a` shows that nothing is listening on port 23. After restarting the service, `netstat -a` shows that it's listening on port 23.

Everything looks correct, but when I try to connect via SecureCRT, the message "***The remote system refused the connection***" is displayed in the terminal window.

I've tried disabling the Windows Firewall, but still get the same result.

That Universe is installed and working is proven by the fact that I can use the Universe Shell. I'd prefer to use SecureCRT instead, but can't even get a login prompt.

Any help would be appreciated; I can't find anything on the net or in the docs that helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have not used the terminal emulator you mentioned.  Yet, I can tell you the error is caused because you are trying to make a secure connection to the UniVerse port which is not setup for secure connections.  Port 23 is the default telnet port set up by UniVerse and is not intended for secure connections.

Comment: I don't think this is correct, as I've configured SecureCRT to use the Telnet protocol, not SSH, Telnet/SSL, or any other. But, hey, it's a thought. I will try using the built-in windows telnet client and see if that works.

Comment: Problem solved. I replaced the machine name with 127.0.0.1 and can connect perfectly. Neither the host name ("Windows81") or "localhost" worked, and a ping test showed that Windows was using IPV6 addresses when either of those was used. I know that I can change the hosts file to force IPV4 for Windows81 or localhost, but using the IP address work for my purposes.